# Can a Pokemon have a status effect and leech seed on at the same time?

Tags: pokemon-series

Can a Pokemon have a status effect and leech seed on at the same time?

Does leech seed count as a status effect?

Answer (score 8):

Yes this is possible. Leech Seed is technically a status effect. It is considered as a [volatile status](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Status_condition#Volatile_status), which can be active alongside other status effects.

[Here is the page](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Leech_Seed_(move)) where you can learn about Leech Seed.

Answer (score -1):

Leech Seed is a status effect, but is volatile.

From Bulbapedia (https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Status_condition#Volatile_battle_status):

> Since [volatile status effects] aren't shown in battle as a status condition (having an icon) **a Pokémon can be affected with multiple volatile battle statuses, volatile conditions and a non-volatile condition at the same time.**

Comment: How is this different from the answer that was already posted?